# Sitemap Generator timed out, maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, laravel, sitemap, laravel-sitemap

I need to generate a sitemap.

I am using [spatie/laravel-sitemap](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap). I have installed and published it but when I run the generator Symphony throws a fatal error: `Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded`.

I have a huge list of links and left just one to test, but still getting the same error.

How to fix that? Here is my `web.php` code:

```
<?php

use Spatie\Sitemap\SitemapGenerator;

// this link throws a fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded
Route::get('sitemap', function(){

    SitemapGenerator::create('127.0.0.1:8000')->writeToFile('sitemap.xml');

    return 'sitemap created';

});

// this link is tested and fully working
Route::get('', function () {
    return view('home');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common problem when working with long running scripts.

Did you try using php function 
[set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) ?

Try putting in the beginning of your script

`set_time_limit(300);`